# How to produce two lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

How do I take a list in haskell and produce two lists as an output?

For example a question I am working on asks to create a program that takes a
predicate and a list and returns a list of two lists, the first
those elements of the input list which pass the predicate, the
second those that don't, in order, e.g

```
 tear (>5) [1,10,2,12,3,13]
```

=> [[10,12,13],[1,2,3]]

What i have so far:

```
tear f [] = []
tear f (x:xs)
 | f x = x: tear f xs
 | otherwise = tear f xs
```

Which produces

```
tear (>5) [1,10,2,12,3,13]
[10,12,13]
```

Comment: If you always want to return two lists, then a 2-tuple of lists probably makes more sense than a list containing lists.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do that? Sorry as I said I’m very new to Haskell

Comment: Why is this question downvoted without explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @WillemVanOnsem's suggestion to use a 2-tuple:

```
tear f [] = ([],[])
tear f (x:xs)
 | f x = (x:y,z)
 | otherwise = (y,x:z)
    where (y,z) = tear f xs
```

Comment: Note that if you really do want a 2-element list and not a tuple, you can just replace all of the round parentheses with square brackets (except on the second line)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i wanted to know!